# How can I make my question more specific?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [How to calculate custom made business hours between two date columns for an entire dataframe? (output as a new column so i can chart it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69455719/how-to-calculate-custom-made-business-hours-between-two-date-columns-for-an-enti)

I got feedback that my question is vague when it seems specific even after edits. How can I ask the question linked above in a better way?

Comment: I think your question in it's current state is fine. It might be missing something required to solve it given that i have no experience with python, but given a specific error message and a line number (which you've provided info for) should be enough for someone to assist or be able to request actionable clarification.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, these past few weeks ive even deleted questions after days of no comments or acknowledgement. I am struggling to even get answers to questions and thought that i wasnt being specific enough when i really try to give everything i've got. I dont know if its because im too new to programming and dont understand how to ask it a certain way or how i can better improve this. I am trying to be a good contributor to this community but so far its been met with some hurdles. @KevinB

Comment: Your title though, should include the error message as that’s what your question is about, not what your app does.

Comment: When you use a 3rd party package that people wouldn't recognize, please specify and link it in your question. People wouldn't understand what your code does without knowing about that package.

Comment: Looking at the question, it's currently very hard for me to see what *specifically* you are asking. The title doesn't make it clear whether your issue is with dataframes, calculating business hours, or plotting; the body contains a single question unrelated to either. The code and traceback are incomplete and weirdly formatted, so unsuitable to replicate/see a specific issue. The rest afterwards is just – I dunno, background, data, a task description, an example? I recommend to consider what your *specific* problem is, then *remove* superfluous content and *focus* on just that one problem.

Comment: I don't understand why this meta question is closed as Needing details or clarity. OP seems to be asking how to improve their question on main, which seems clear enough to me.

Comment: I've read the feedback and taken it into consideration. I do think that stack overflow sites are not beginner friendly nor gentle. Kind of coms with the territory i guess when working with engineers etc... but i understand why focusing so much on only a specific problem would make most sense. I didnt know people needed me to link them code libraries either, again, being new how could i know? i will take this advice and apply it to my next question i post. thank you all for taking time to help me out here

Comment: Perhaps you should apply some of it to your current post as well. Like the suggestion to change the title. Post are edited to make improvement all the time. Because every post kept is suppose to last.

Comment: eh... Blame the company, not us (re: availability of rules) :) We've been complaining for years about making rules easier to discover, understand, and apply. Unfortunately, not much has changed in that regards. As for the "comes with territory" - I do not think so, many of us a friendly bunch, this is just Internet where folks tend to be blunter than they would be in a face-to-face conversation. Besides, SO used to be a much harsher place if you remember the older times, actually

Comment: @Scratte i will do this now! thank you :) and @ OlegValter yeah maybe i was too harsh with my "comes with territory" comment sorry bout that one.

Comment: You may also want to check out chat. Sometimes you can find helpful people there too :) Just make sure you understand the rules of the different rooms. Some don't really like it if you just drop in and ask about your post :)

Comment: [The help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) is actually not that bad (e.g., is of an appropriate length (not too terse and not too long)): *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* (not RTFM). It also links to Jon Skeet's *[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)* (still not RTFM).

Comment: @Scratte i got access to chat yesterday! ill give it a try, seems daunting at first haha

Comment: @PeterMortensen what is RTFM?

Comment: @JonOneill I use chat all the time. It's very helpful for me :) RTFM is short for Read The F.... (Fine? Fantastic?. not really, but it starts with F) Manual :)